# Dynamics 365. Field value (javascript)

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

How can I get field value in Dynamics 365 with JavaScript?
In browser console function `Xrm.Page()` return undefined.
And when I try get some attribute like a

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_city").getValue();
```

receive error in browser console:

> Unable to get property 'getValue' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [crm 2011 xrm.page.getattribute returns null when there is value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27489835/crm-2011-xrm-page-getattribute-returns-null-when-there-is-value)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can approach this issue

1. In the 'target' dropdown in the top right corner of your Developer Tools window, switch to 'Client API Wrapper'.  You should then be able to access the form with your javascript code.  Your syntax is correct.
2. Append the beginning of your code with frames at index 0

example:

```
    var city = frames[0].Xrm.Page.getAttribute('bah_city').getValue();
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you havent select the right frame, in the upper left corner of the console you should changed to **customScriptsFrame** and execute you code

Hope it helps.

Regards

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Xrm.Page()` probably isnt a method that exists. Try `Xrm.Page` instead.

For `Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_city")`, are you certain:

- The field is on the form.
- The field name is spelt correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:
     `Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_city").getValue();` should work.

Make sure you are using the Name exactly as it is seen in the Field Properties.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons are given in other answers.

To avoid errors, always use null check.

```
if(Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_city") != null)
    var city = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_city").getValue();
```

If you are using this field in header, then use this:

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("header_new_city").getValue();
```

If you are using this field in Business Process Flow, then use this:

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("header_process_new_city").getValue();
```